# How do you "end" align a flex column in Bootstrap 4, whilst keeping them the same height?

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm still trying to get my head around some bits with the new Flex stuff in Bootstrap. I have to admit, I've not really played with Flex prior to this (as it wasn't properly supported in a lot of older versions).

Anyway, here is a CodePen of what I'm doing:

http://codepen.io/youradds/pen/egLoVq

Basically, I want all the columns to be the same height *BUT* have the content aligned to the bottom of the cells.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-secondary align-self-end">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="checkbox" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
        Piscine
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-secondary align-self-end">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="checkbox" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
        foo bar<br>
        foo bar<br>
        foo bar<br>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-secondary align-self-end">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="checkbox" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
        foo bar<br>
        foo bar<br>
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-secondary align-self-end">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="checkbox" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
        foo bar<br>
        foo bar<br>
        foo bar<br>
        foo bar<br>
      </label>    
      <label class="btn btn-secondary align-self-end">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" class="checkbox" value="1" autocomplete="off" />
        foo bar<br>
        foo bar<br>
        foo bar<br>
      </label>    
</div>
```

But as you can see, it doesn't keep the rows all the same height:

[image]

I've tried quite a few things, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not responding your question but I'm standing where you are, learning Flex. I found this awesome tutorial to get you started with flex. http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: @Alan haha thanks - will give that a go :) Always good having visual suggestions on how stuff works.

Comment: I also just found this helpful tutorial. https://designmodo.com/bootstrap-4-flexbox/  . I think its a little bit out of date (due to the fact it was written Jan 2016, and there have been a few beta's, and now an alpha release since, with quite a lot of changes). Still, it helped me understand it a bit more - so worth a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

You have one flex container: `div.btn-group`

You have five flex items: `label.btn`

Each flex item has a Bootstrap class aligning it to the bottom of the container: `align-self-end`

With the code above, your flex items will no longer occupy the full height of the container, because the `align-self-end` class is overriding the default setting of `align-self: stretch`.

### Solution

Try this:

1. Remove `align-self-end` from all flex items. (Now the default `stretch` prevails and the items are full height.)
2. Make each flex item a (nested) flex container.
3. Give this new container `align-items: flex-end`.

This allows the primary items to maintain their full height, while aligning the nested items (the actual content) to the bottom.

In a nutshell, the solution is to remove the Bootstrap `align-self-end` class and add this to your CSS:

```
.btn {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Or, in Bootstrap code, adjust each `label` element to look like this:

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary d-flex align-items-end">
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgaowJ?editors=1100)